# Executing dynamic python function in response to HTTP Call

Tags: python, bottle

I have a http server written using bottle which has 2 URLS. Save/Update Code and Execute Code. I am passing a raw python file to save/update code and saving it in file system and returning a code id. I want to execute the code whenever a http request comes to /execute/{codeid}. I want to pass the parameters i received for the endpoint /execute/{codeid} to the raw python file i stored.

I am confused as to how to pass parameters to the dynamic python file. I am trying to create something similar to webtask.io using python.

I have tried to use code to create dynamic functions using the below given code. But it only creates a function. I want to import other modules also.

```
import types
import sys,imp

code = """def f(a,b,c):
print a+b+c, "really WoW"
"""
module = imp.new_module('myfunctions')
exec code in module.__dict__
module.f('W', 'o', 'W')
```

Comment: Found the solution. The solution can be found in the given gist url.
If any suggestions for the below code i will be really happy @samaksh-jain https://gist.github.com/mdathersajjad/45eeca684a8ead6fe9173cbab3595e61

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to execute code from a user and provide dynamic input.

Why not use something like: `subprocess.call('python file_<codeid>.py <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>', shell=True)`

You save the code in python file, then run it with arguments, get and validate the output from this.

Comment: You are correct i want to execute user provided code with dynamic input. Args can be string only right. I want to pass the request and response object itself to the user defined code. It is just going to be defining one method which will take the values from the request do some processing on it and write the result to the response stream.

Comment: So did you try it with `subprocess.call()` ?